# How to change the menu postion respectively in onclick function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menu

I new to jQuery I have menu like following type [image: menu]

After click the some menu I want to change the menu position like this [image: menuposition] and then click another menu position like this [image: menuposition]. How to change the position of menu after reloading page respectively?

Comment: What about posting some code?...

Comment: Please provide us with your attempt to do this. You cant expect people to write you free code based on your drawings.

Comment: @roasted sorry I am trying only just changing the text and background color on click function not try any thing in position changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to style the elements with classes such as

```
'main'
'sub'.
```

The one with the class of main with have CSS styling to put it on the left.

Then using jQuery, switch the classes round upon a click!

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(a).removeClass('main');
    $(this).addClass('main');
});
```

Comment: That will not work for all cases since the place to return to for the open menu is always different. A single class cant place the element dynamically.

Comment: @DreamWave i was just laying out the prototype, go figure out the rest!

Comment: @InGodITrust Thanks for your reply..I need to create two classes for every menu?

Comment: @SKM you should probably have a class for each, and on each click switch the classes!

Comment: @InGodITrust I follow your way but when I click the menu after reloading  the page it will be change the default position

Answer (score 0):

For detecting the classname `.sub#` to be swapped with the `.main` class you can use regex, for example

HTML:

```html
<div class="menu main">menu 1</div>
<div class="menu sub1">menu 2</div>
<div class="menu sub2">menu 3</div>
<div class="menu sub3">menu 4</div>
<div class="menu sub4">menu 5</div>
```

jQuery code:

```js
$(function () {
    $('div.menu').click(function () {
        var cls = $(this).prop("class");
        var m = cls.match(/(?:\s*)(sub\d+)(?:\s*)/);
        if (!m) {
            return;
        }
        cls =  m[1];
        $('div.main').removeClass('main').addClass(cls);
        $(this).removeClass(cls).addClass('main');
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrRXH/3/)

Comment: Ok how to replace the image position like above type. can u help me?

Comment: You can change images like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/hrRXH/2/ (Also fixed the class assignment for the main menu item.)

Comment: When I click the image after refreshing page again to change the default postion

Comment: When page is refreshed, DOM is renewed.So you can either use a cookie or localStorage to make changes permanent in visitor's browser. Like for example this: http://jsfiddle.net/hrRXH/5/